# CSS float and auto height

Tags: html, css

How to get `height:auto;` for a parent element when child elements use `float:left;` or `float:right`?

parent

```
#parent {
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        background:#0F0;
}
```

child_left

```
#child_left {
    width:50%;
    height:50px;
        float:left;
            background:#00F;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27EWw/

Comment: by doing `height:auto;`, what do you want it to do?

Comment: Is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/27EWw/1/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default height of an element is `auto`, but it seems like are you looking for a clearfix. If an element's children are floated, they are essentially taken out of the flow of the document, therefore if the parent doesn't have defined dimensions, it will collapse upon itself. You could add `overflow:auto` to the parent element:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tYyJB/)

```
#parent {
    width:100px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    background:#0F0;
}
```

Alternatively you could also use a clearfix:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nM6jj/)

```
#parent:after {
    clear:both;
    display:table;
    content:'';
}
```

You could also have a clearfix class, either options would work. If you wanted to avoid these options, you would simply have to set dimensions on the parent element in the first place. Obviously, this isn't always the best option as some elements will have children with varying dimensions.